# Adding Url prefix according the level of category in Magento

Tags: magento

How to add url prefix according to the level of categories

Example :-

```
example.com/h/lvl-1-categories
example.com/s/lvl-2-categories
```

Etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :

Copied

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php

to

/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php

in Url.php find the lines

```
    if (null === $parentPath) {
        $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
    }
    elseif ($parentPath == '/') {

        $parentPath = '';

   }
```

and replace with

```
//        if (null === $parentPath) {
//            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
//        }
//        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
        if($category->getLevel() > 2){
            $parentPath = 'c/';
        }else{
            $parentPath = 'h/';
        }

//        }
```

Modified the answer from http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32328/